# Please identify this algorithm: probabilistic top-k elements in a data stream

Tags: algorithm, stream

I remember hearing about the following algorithm some years back, but can't find any reference to it online. It identifies the top *k* elements (or heavy hitters) in a data stream of *n* elements using only *m* counters. This is particularly useful for finding top search terms, network abusers, etc. while using minimal memory.

The algorithm: for each element,

1. If the element does not already have a counter and counters < *m*, create a counter for the element and initialize to 1.

   Else if the element does have a counter, increment it.

   Else if the element does not have a counter and counters > *m*, decrement an existing counter *c*. If *c* reaches 0, replace its corresponding element, with the current element. (*c* is an index into the list of existing counters, where *c* increases in round robin fashion for each element that reaches this step.)

I have found many other similar algorithms (many of which are listed, though not described, in this wikipedia article about [streaming algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm#Heavy_hitters)), but not this one.
I particularly like it because it is as simple to implement as it is to describe.

But I'd like to learn more about its probabilistic characteristics- if I'm only interested in the top 100 items, what effect does using 1,000 counters instead of 100 counters have?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it looks like [space-saving](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~leichen/courses/comp5331/lectures/efficient_computation_of_frequent_and_top_k_elements_in_data.pdf) by A. Metwally et al.

Comment: @erickson not my vote, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about the notable Misra-Gries Algorithm, and Space-Saving Algorithm is a faster version of Misra-Gries Algorithm.  Please check this lecture note for detail [Streaming Algorithm Dartmouth](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS49-Fall11/Notes/lecnotes.pdf) sec 1.2.

One thing I want to point out is that this algorithm does not give you the top-k elements if you only used k counters, instead, it gives all elements with frequency >  m / k, where m is the total length of the data stream.

Detailed analysis can be found in the lecture notes I attached.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the "Frequent" algorithm. It uses *k* - 1 counters to find all elements that exceed 1/*k* of the total, and was published in 1982 by Misra and Gries. It's a generalization of Boyer and Moore's (or Fischer-Salzberg's) "Majority" algorithm, where *k* is 2. These and related algorithms are introduced in a helpful article, ["The Britney Spears Problem."](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/the-britney-spears-problem)

I give a [detailed explanation of the algorithm elsewhere on StackOverflow,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260905/3474) which I won't repeat here. The important point is that, after one pass, the counter values don't precisely indicate the frequency of an item; they can under-count by a margin that depends on the length of the stream and inversely on the number of counters (*n / k*). All of these algorithms (including Metwally's "SpaceSaving") require a second pass if you want an exact count rather than an estimate of frequency.

Comment: I actually remember having read that article when it was published. But there is a difference in the algorithms in step 3. The algorithm in the article would decrement all counters, whereas the one I've described would only decrement a single counter. I vaguely recollect that being an important factor. It makes it more efficient, but I don't know how it affects the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the CPU cache replacement algoritme [Least frequently used (LFU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_frequently_used)

The algorithm: for each element,

1. If the element does not already have a counter and counters < m,
   create a counter for the element and initialize to 1. 
   a. if the cache is not full add the line.
2. Else if the element does have a counter, increment it.
   a. increment the cache line counter
3. Else if the element does not have a counter and counters > m, decrement an existing counter. If c reaches 0, replace its corresponding element, with the current element. (c is an index into the list of existing counters,
   where c increases in round robin fashion for each element that
   reaches this step.)

   - a. advance to the next candidate cache line
   - b. decrement the current candidates counter
   - c. if it hasn't reached zero go to a.
   - d. evict the cache line and replace it with the new.