# how can i find top 10 hashtags from stream of billion tweets

Tags: language-agnostic, twitter

This was an interview question that someone asked me and I didn't really have a  good answer. I was wondering if someone could possibly help me understand the solution to this:

"You have a stream of billion tweets coming in. How will you figure out the top 10 hashtags ? "

Thanks

Comment: @EricPetroelje Can you elaborate on that please ?

Comment: @EricPetroelje Statistical sampling won't find the `top 10`. it will find 10 hashtags with high probability to be in the top 10

Comment: String a couple buzzwords together and put MapReduce in them... if he expects a "stream" of 1 billion tweets means 3 whole days worth of worldwide twitter usage, he's probably not going to know the real answer anyway.

Comment: @alfasin - agreed, and elaborated a bit in my answer.  The problem is easy to solve if you assume you can actually analyze all the tweets, but I think they were hoping you would realize that you can't really do that and come up with a practical alternative.

Comment: @EricPetroelje I also agree with you that the question, the way it was put, is not realistic. And this is exactly why an important part of  answering interview-questions is to ask questions yourself, to make sure that you're not making any (wrong) assumptions. For any job-seeker, I recommend reading: http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a map, with a hashtag as the key and a counter as a value.

Increment the counter of each tag in each tweet you receive.

Examine the value of the counters to find the top 10.

Your phrasing of the question doesn't include any constraints that would prohibit this straightforward solution. In an interview situation, I would have asked clarifying questions to elicit these constraints.

Under constraints like, "it has to run in linear time," and, "it has to use a constant amount of memory," much more interesting answers emerge.

---

I am not sure if there is a constant memory solution to the problem as posed, but I know one for a related (and often more useful) problem: identifying elements that constitute a given fraction of results. I gave it [as an answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260905/3474)

(I say, "more useful", because if the total fraction of a given item falls below a threshold, it's more likely to be noise than true "Top 10" material.)

Comment: With a billion tweets streaming in, don't you think there will be memory problems if we use a map ? Also, the interviewer kept it open ended by not specifying constraints. I'd imagine with this answer, he'd make memory a constraint, then what would I do ?

Comment: With the caveat that, depending on the number of hashtags, you may need to offload the map to a database table or something similar, this is the perfect answer. Especially when you consider the constraints aspect, which is probably what the interviewer was looking for.

Comment: @brainydexter don't let my previous comment fool you - chances are unlikely that you'd need to offload the map to the DB. Given that we can store a hash in as many bytes as the hashtag is long, and most tags will be repeated many times, if you think about it that's only like maybe 8-10ish GB of memory, which you can easily distribute over a number of servers if needed.

Comment: @corsiKa This all sounds too simple :) A followup thought that comes to my mind. Lets say after a certain capacity of hashmap, we offload it to database. Lets imagine, we get about a million unique hashtags. To find the top 10 hashtags from this database would be a pretty time consuming query. What do you suggest ?

Comment: @brainydexter Well, either it could keep an index on the tags as it went (which wouldn't be too bad) or keep it unindexed and only sort. As you can see from this link, a little Java I wrote in a few minutes, a server with particularly limiting resources was able to sort 5 million records in under a second. I can only imagine that a database server would perform much better. Link: http://ideone.com/Avid7

Comment: @corsiKa I get it. I'm going to ask another variant of this: What if we were restricted by constant amount of memory ?

Comment: @brainydexter tough to say. Let's use a contrived example that you're limited to 1000 tags in memory. So you're trucking along and at about tweet 10mil, you have exhausted your 1000 tags. Well that's not good, you're only 1% through your tweets. Well now you need to drop one. Clearly, we will want to drop the lowest count, since it's the least important thus far. Let's call this outgoing tag `X` and the incoming tag `Y`. Next tag is also new, so `Z` replaces `Y`. The entire rest of the tweets are nothing but existing X Y and Z in order such that they constantly... (continued)

Comment: get dropped from the bottom. Well, that's just great. They should be the top 3 tags, with roughly 330 mil entries each. But instead we've just dropped them constantly, so their counts never really got past 1. So this kind of problem doesn't really have a decent solution in constant memory, unless you plan to do something like a double nested loop, which would just be awful, and require that you save all the tweets, which is going to much more than just storing the tags.

Comment: @brainydexter No, I don't think there will be memory problems. I would expect the number of distinct keys in the map to be on the order of a few tens of thousands (they are chosen for categorization, or grouping, so they are a subset of common words). A 32-bit counter would be plenty, too.

Comment: @corsiKa There is a constant memory, linear time solution to a similar problem: identifying all elements that comprise a given fraction of the stream. If you or braindexter are interested in that, I can amend my answer, but I'm not sure it's necessary in this scenario.

Comment: @erickson I am quite interested in such an answer. Links and/or amendments are most welcome. Its principles actually may come in quite handy for an upcoming project here at work regarding document management.

Comment: @corsiKa I added a link to a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't analyze all the tweets, so you just analyze a random sample.  Find the top 10 from that sample and you can find the top 10 (to some degree of certainty, depending on the sample size and quality of the sample).

I don't think they were looking for an actual solution here, but more probing your thought process on how you might solve a (practically) impossible problem.

Comment: Why couldn't you analyze all the tweets? It's like... 140Gb of material, max. That's not very much...

Comment: @corsiKa - You could, but the question doesn't specify anything about the rate at which the tweets are coming in.  A billion a minute? an hour? a day?  If they just wanted to know if you were able to use a Map data structure with a counter, then there's no need to make it a stream of a billion tweets - 1000 tweets would be just fine.