# Find top 10 integers among 100 different files

Tags: algorithm

I am a fresher and preparing for interviews. In my recent interview I was asked a question, for which I couldn't find suitable answer.

I was given some 100 files, each file is containing large number of comma separated integers. I had to find the top 10 integers among the whole files. I tried to solve it using heap. But I got confused with the time complexity of the process. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate - [Algorithm to find top 10 search terms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260653/algorithm-to-find-top-10-search-terms?rq=1).

Comment: Do the files contain unique numbers? That is, can the number 42 appear multiple times in a single file?

Comment: Are you looking for the 10 largest integers, or the 10 integers that have the most occurrences?

Comment: I was asked the top ten largest integers from the whole files

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track with using a heap data structure.

You could process the files in parallel and for each file you could maintain a min-heap of size 10.

As you iterate through a file you insert a value into the min-heap until it is full (size 10) then for values in positions 11 through n

```
if current_value > min_heap.current()
    min_heap.extract()
    min_heap.insert(current_value)
```

You have to iterate through n values and the worst case scenario is if the file is sorted in ascending order. In that case you will have to extract the min value and insert a new value for all the values in positions 11 thru n. The heap operations will be O(log n) giving you an overall running time of O(n * log n) for each file.

At this point you have m (# of files) min-heaps each of size 10. Here you can use a final min heap to store the ten largest numbers contained in the m min-heaps. This computation will be O(m) because the all the heaps at this point will be of max size 10, a constant.

Overall the running time will be O(n * log n + m). m could be much smaller than n so amongst friends we could say O(n * log n).

Even if you don't do the first step in parallel it would be O(m * n * log n + m), but once again if n dominates m we could say O(n * log n).

Comment: thanks for your algorithm, it helped me getting rid of my confusion :)

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't work. Imagine you're looking for the most common number (just one) among three files. In those files, the number 7 occurs 8 times in each file. But it's the second most common number in each file. In every file, there is some other number that occurs more often, but *overall* the number 7 occurs more often than any other number. Your algorithm would give the wrong answer.

Comment: I misinterpreted the "top 10 integers". I thought that meant the largest integers in the files not the integers with the most occurrences.

Comment: With that interpretation your algorithm works. And the OP's question is ambiguous. So you probably didn't deserve the downvote. I've reversed it.