# keeping n maximal frequencies of numbers in endless stream

Tags: java, algorithm

Given **endless** stream of numbers (BigInteger) how can the numbers with **top N appearances** (frequencies) be detected and stored?

The memory is limited (cannot store counter per number).

**EDIT:**

the frequency value cannot exceed size of `long`

Comment: @moooeeeep, the stream is endless and the memory is limited (see the question) so the answer is 'No'

Comment: [Streaming algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm) might help here.

Comment: This post seems to be related, possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1151015/126916

Comment: what is the memory limit? if it's max of biginteger there is no problem and you can use naive algorithm. Or it's limited to N?

Comment: @dfens There is no max value of `BigInteger` -- it's arbitrarily precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top N appearances cannot be determined until you have all the data (or most of it)

You can determine the N appearance so far by counting how often they have appeared and sorting them by count. This could be a problem if you can't store than many in which case you have to decide what compromises you are will to make to save space.

I assume `long` is not large enough. What sort of data are you counting?

---

A trivial example which demonstrates the problem you face.

Say your endless stream of account ids are all different.  This means the *only* way to record the top N is to record them all.  Without some short cuts, there is not other possible solution.

Note: it is likely what you really want it a decaying average so that if a user has been seen for some time you want to reduce their weight.  You don't want the top user to be one which is no longer active.

Comment: I am counting entities (user accounts) with IDs of type `BigInteger` and want to keep record of N most frequently visiting users.

Comment: I am surprised you have more than 18 trillion trillion accounts ids but all the same you have to count them all as you never know when the most frequent account will start. What you can do is keep the most frequent in batches and keep the top 2*N to appropriate the top N but only you know what short cuts you can take in sampling the data.

Comment: @aviad Do you have a bound on the number of user accounts? Why do you use `BigIntegers`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm even more surprised that he'd like to know that for all visits instead of those for the most recent year/month which would make the task that much easier.

Comment: @aviad as you store all IDs from all user accounts, you already take up infinite memory, don't you?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, the ID was designed this way (I guess the DBAs are the ones to blame).

Comment: @moooeeeep, and if they are not all in the memory :)?

Comment: @aviad You have to determine which ones you can discard in the hope it won't make much difference. What works for you depends on the pattern of your data. There is no strategy which will work in all cases.

Comment: @aviad They might not all be in the memory but if you're going to count them you have to use some memory for every one of them. Your question is not solvable as you presented it. Edit and add some constraints.

Comment: @ipavlic, maybe not for all of them simultaneously?

Comment: @aviad Yes, for all of them simultaneously. Otherwise a counterexample can be constructed easily. E.g. an element that appears regularly but rarely, and a set of elements that appear just once but in very dense configurations. Depending on the timeline, either the slow-but-steady or fast-or-furious elements are most frequent. Peter's example is even better. What if you have elements 0-(f+1) which all appear just once.

Comment: @aviad so what assumptions can be made about the data which allow you to reduce which accounts are counted? BTW There are systems which try to detect hacking by counting the frequency of access, so hackers try to appear too infrequent to matter.

Answer (score 1):

If the stream is endless, some numbers of lower frequency can become more frequent. That means you have to update the frequencies for all numbers.

On the other hand, as there is no bound for `BigIntegers`, you have infinite storage requirements: for every number `n`, you have to store at least some information (let's say a bit). If the memory is finite `f`, there is another integer `m` such that `m * n > f`.

The problem cannot be solved without some additional constraints.

### edit

As you indicate you'd like to keep track of visitor counts. Wouldn't it be easier to just count them for the last year or month? You'd just have a dictionary (visitor,visits) pairs. As for BigIntegers - you plan on having more than 2^63-1 users?

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the distribution is stationary and you accept an approximate result you can estimate the result based on a finite sample of numbers from your stream.